# In a tabular, how do I reduce the vertical space in a wrapped text?

Tags: tables, line-spacing

In a tabular, I am using the commands that allows you to wrap your text:

```
\begin{tabular}{m{5cm} m{13cm} m{5cm}}
```

but I would like to change the vertical space between the different lines of the wrapped up text: that is, if I write

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{slides}

\usepackage[landscape,top=0.01pt, bottom=0.01pt, left=0.01pt, right=0.01pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{5cm} m{13cm} m{5cm}}
  \large{Journee} & \huge{Le Tour de France des dechiffreurs} & Confer'ENS 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want the space between the different lines of "Le tour de France des Dechiffreurs" to be smaller.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own `\Huge` with a smaller `\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{slides}

\usepackage[landscape,top=0.01pt, bottom=0.01pt, left=0.01pt, right=0.01pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\myHuge{\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{5cm} m{13cm} m{5cm}}
  \large{Journee} & \myHuge  Le Tour de France des dechiffreurs & Confer'ENS 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If all four margins of the document are equal in size (as in the present example), one could use the option `margin=0.01pt` in the invocation of the `geometry` package. :-)